# kubectl: Error from server: No SSH tunnels currently open

Tags: ssh, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running some containers on Google Container Engine.
One day everything was fine, and the next day I can't `attach` to my containers anymore. Or `exec`, or any other docker command.

I deleted the pods and let new ones be instanced, didn't help.
Then I deleted the node and waited for a new one to be created and the pods deployed, didn't help either.

```
$ kubectl attach www-controller-dev-xxxxx

Error from server: No SSH tunnels currently open. Were the targets able to accept an ssh-key for user "gke-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"?
```

What else can I try?

The problem might have started after I've deleted the cluster and recreated it, but I can't be sure. Did that before and it never was a problem.

Answer (score 16):

Commands like attach rely on the cluster's master being able to talk to the nodes
in the cluster. However, because the master isn't in the same Compute
Engine network as your cluster's nodes, we rely on SSH tunnels to enable secure
communication.

Container Engine puts an SSH public key in your Compute Engine project
[metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata). All Compute Engine VMs using
Google-provided images regularly check their project's common metadata
and their instance's metadata for SSH keys to add to the VM's list of
authorized users. Container Engine also adds a firewall rule to your Compute
Engine network allowing SSH access from the master's IP address to each node
in the cluster.

If kubectl attach (or logs, exec, and port-forward) doesn't work, it's likely that it's because the master is unable to open SSH tunnels to the nodes. To
determine what the underlying problem is, you should check for these potential
causes:

1. The cluster doesn't have any nodes.

   If you've scaled down the number of nodes in your cluster to zero, SSH
   tunnels won't work.

   To fix it,
   [resize your cluster](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/resizing-a-replication-controller/)
   to have at least one node.
2. Pods in the cluster have gotten stuck in a terminating state and prevented
   nodes that no longer exist from being removed from the cluster.

   This is an issue that should only affect Kubernetes version 1.1, but could
   be caused by repeated resizing of the cluster down and up.

   To fix it,
   [delete the pods](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_delete/)
   that have been in a terminating state for more than a few minutes.
   The old nodes will then be removed from the master's API and replaced
   by the new nodes.
3. Your network's firewall rules don't allow for SSH access to the master.

   All Compute Engine networks are created with a firewall rule called
   "default-allow-ssh" that allows SSH access from all IP addresses (requiring
   a valid private key, of course). Container Engine also inserts an SSH rule
   for each cluster of the form "gke---ssh"
   that allows SSH access specifically from the cluster's master IP to the
   cluster's nodes. If neither of these rules exists, then the master will be
   unable to open SSH tunnels.

   To fix it,
   [re-add a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall)
   allowing access to VMs with the tag that's on all the cluster's nodes from
   the master's IP address.
4. Your project's common metadata entry for sshKeys is full.

   If the project's metadata entry named "sshKeys" is close to the 32KiB size
   limit, then Container Engine isn't able to add its own SSH key to let it
   open SSH tunnels. You can see your project's metadata by running
   `gcloud compute project-info describe [--project=PROJECT]`, then check the
   length of the list of sshKeys.

   To fix it,
   [delete some of the SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#delete_project-wide_ssh_keys)
   that are no longer needed.
5. You have set a metadata field with the key "sshKeys" on the VMs in the
   cluster.

   The node agent on VMs prefers per-instance sshKeys to project-wide SSH keys,
   so if you've set any SSH keys specifically on the cluster's nodes, then the
   master's SSH key in the project metadata won't be respected by the nodes.
   To check, run `gcloud compute instances describe <VM-name>` and look for
   an "sshKeys" field in the metadata.

   To fix it,
   [delete the per-instance SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#delete_instance-only_ssh-keys_values)
   from the instance metadata.

It's worth noting that these features are not required for the correct
functioning of the cluster. If you prefer to keep your cluster's network locked
down from all outside access, that's perfectly fine. Just be aware that
features like these won't work as a result.

Comment: 1. The cluster did have running nodes and runnning pods.

2. None of the pods was terminating.

3. I did not change anything on the firewall rules and the default `default-allow-ssh` rule still exists.

4. I checked the length of the list of sshKeys, it contained only 2 keys.

5. I have not manually set a metadata field with the key "sshKeys".


It just stopped working suddenly. The first time deleting the cluster didn't help. The second time I deleted the cluster (next day) it helped, now I can `kubectl attach` and `kubectl exec` again.

Comment: How do I find the master's IP address? Is it the same as "Endpoint" in cluster's details?

Comment: Great answer! As little side-node: If the masters SSH-Key is missing/was removed from sshKeys-metadata, it gets re-added automatically after some time after you've cleaned up SSH-Keys.

Comment: One thing to add, that I just hit, is that if you turn on the "OS login" feature at the Google Project level you can hit this condition. This feature turns off the SSH keys being shared from project metadata, and therefore you break the SSH connectivity between master and the nodes. You can however disable "OS login" for the nodes as per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts you just saved me hours upon hours of pain. Thanks for posting that!!

Comment: This answer is also on official GKE troubleshooting  page https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#kubect_commands_hang

Comment: I worked there when I wrote the answer, so it's certainly within their rights to put it in the docs if they want :)

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to consider: regional clusters. Regional clusters have multiple masters and the cluster endpoint is a load balancer.
So, review your network routes!

If you have a VM instance acting as NAT gateway, you may have some routes forcing traffic trough it. So you must exclude from these routes the traffic between multiple Kubernetes masters and nodes.

You can find your master IPs by inspecting the firewall rule named `gke-<cluster_name>-<short_uid>-ssh`, then create routes to bypass the NAT gateway.

Here's `gcloud` commands to find GKE master IPs:
`bash
FW_RULE_GKE_SSH=$(gcloud compute firewall-rules list --filter="name~'gke-.*-ssh'" --format="get(name)")
GKE_MASTER_IP=$(gcloud compute firewall-rules describe ${FW_RULE_GKE_SSH} --format='value(sourceRanges)')`

Special thanks for this issue and fix on this Terraform module: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/issues/25

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. All network traffic was going through a VPN tunnel and a custom NAT gateway on the other end of the tunnel. I had to add routes with priority 99 to the network to the masters as described here.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very good answer, but it's the only thing I got:

The first time deleting the cluster didn't help. The second time I deleted the cluster (the next day) it helped, now I can `kubectl attach` and `kubectl exec` again.

Might also have been just a temporary problem of the Google Container platform and nothing at all to do with me re-creating the cluster.