# How to find control plane IP addresses for a regional GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I mistakenly deleted the firewall entry that allows the control plane nodes to establish [ssh tunnels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375030/kubectl-error-from-server-no-ssh-tunnels-currently-open) to the worker nodes. I need to recreate the firewall entry, but I can't find the IP addresses of the controller nodes.

This is a regional cluster, so the cluster endpoint is a load balancer that sits in front of the 3 control plane IPs. I don't see that load balancer in my GCP console though, so I can't get its details.

How do I find the IP addresses of the 3 control plane nodes in a GKE regional cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should have been a log created when the rules were deleted. The IP addresses are in there. You can pull them out with something like this:

```
gcloud logging read 'resource.type="gce_firewall_rule" AND \
timestamp>="2020-11-01T00:00:00Z" AND \
protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.firewalls.delete" AND \
protoPayload.resourceName:gke'
```

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't able to come up with the right search expression on my own.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#step_1_view_control_planes_cidr_block) you can see the control plane CIDR block of GKE cluster. Use below gcloud command:

```
gcloud container clusters describe cluster-name --zone cluster-zone
```

As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#step_1_view_control_planes_cidr_block) if you delete or modify the firewall rules created by GKE you might encounter unexpected behavior in your clusters.

Also as per this GCP [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.zones.clusters) masterIpv4CidrBlock is deprecated.

Comment: That doc is for a private, zonal cluster. This is a public, regional cluster. There's no `masterIpv4CidrBlock` field in that output.

Comment: If you deleted or modified FW rules that created by GKE then your cluster might not working properly as [per](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules)

Comment: @ChrisJones masterIpv4CidrBlock is depricated.

Comment: There's nothing in the output of that command that could be the control plane CIDR. The closest thing is the endpoint IP, but that only works for zonal clusters, not regional ones.

Answer (score 0):

we can find the private ip of  control plane of GKE cluster using below command

`gcloud container clusters describe cluster-name --zone zone-name --format="value(privateClusterConfig)"`

for eg : `gcloud container clusters describe private-cluster-0 --zone us-east1-b --format="value(privateClusterConfig)"`